# conditional density wrt lebesgue measure

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, stochastic-processes

$X,Y$ are two r.v. $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P}) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ and have joint density wrt to $\lambda^2$, the two dimensional lebesgue measure.

So $f_X(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x,y)\lambda(dy) > 0$ for $\mathbb{P}^X$-a.s. $x \in \mathbb{R}$. And $f_X^{-1}(x)$ ist the density for $\lambda$ absolutely continuous wrt $P^X$.

is then $\int_A \mathbb{P}[X \in dx] = \int_A f_X(x)\lambda(dx)$ ?

Comment: Fubini: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli.27s_theorem_for_non-negative_functions

Comment: $P(X\in A) = P(X\in A, Y\in\mathbb{R}) = \int_{A\times\mathbb{R}} f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,d\lambda^2(x,y) = \int_A\left(\int_\mathbb{R} f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,d\lambda(y)\right)d\lambda(x) = \int_A f_X(x)\,d\lambda(x)$

Comment: that is not true, this holds: $\int_A \mathbb{P}(X \in dx) \int_B f_{Y|X}(x,y)\lambda(dy) = \int_{A \times B}f(x,y)\lambda^2(dx,dy)$

Comment: I wrote four equalities. Which one "doesn't hold"?

Comment: oh sry my mistake :), $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_{X,Y}(x,y)d\lambda(y) = 1$ it is true so everythin is fine. thank you it solved my problem.

Comment: No: $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_{X,Y}(x,y)d\lambda(y) = f_X(x)$, the marginal density of $X$.